# Win32 filesystem "FILE_SUPPORTS_POSIX_UNLINK_RENAME" - what does it do?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, ntfs, smb, refs

Does anyone know what the win32 filesystem attribute "FILE_SUPPORTS_POSIX_UNLINK_RENAME" does ? What is the difference in filesystem behaviour ?

Comment: this mean that fs support [`FileRenameInformationEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_rename_information) with `FILE_RENAME_POSIX_SEMANTICS`